# What is the name of the Phoenician religion?

Tags: religion, terminology, phoenicia

I am writing an article about a Phoenician king, Ithobaal I, and was curious about what religion Phoenicians had. Is there any technical term for it or is it just "Phoenician Religion" or "Phoenician Mythology"?

Comment: The most relevant Wikipedia page is probably [Ancient Canaanite religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Canaanite_religion).

Comment: Perhaps Baalism? http://www.dictionary.com/browse/baalism

Comment: @AllInOne That is specifically the worship of Baal. It doesn't include Astarte of which Ithobaal was a priest prior to him becoming king

Comment: [Religion is probably correct rather than mythology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_and_mythology) depending on the context.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ancient religions don't generally have technical names, at least not at the civilizational level. Think "Ancient Greek religion", "Ancient Egyptian religion", etc.

[Here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1357208) is a technical article summarizing what little is known about Phoenician religion (as of 1990 anyway). It is aptly titled "Phoenician Religion" and does not offer a general alternative term.

Comment: They certainly didn't call themselves "ancient greeks" :)